# Install additional python package to an app compiled with PyInstaller

Tags: python, installation, package, pyinstaller

I have an app that is already compiled thanks to PyInstaller with a limited amount of python packages. The app has been compiled with the --onefile option. I'd like to add the possibility to install any new package in the temporary environment at the launch of the app, but there is no pip (it doesn't matter that the package needs to be installed at each run, this is a very specific option of my app).

While the app was running, I tried to copy/paste manually a random package in the temporary _MEIXXXXX folder. That's quite a dirty way but it worked, I could use the python package.

Do you know if it's possible to do so in a better way ?

Comment: I don't think this is possible... or I should say it isn't possible with what is already builtin to pyinstaller, since it doesn't compile with pip or a python executable at all

Comment: Did you manage to solve this? I am in the same situation. I tried using `subprocess.Popen` with `sys.executable -m pip install <...>` but PyInstaller modifies the sys.executable value as it does not include the python interpreter.